# Unable to ping managed nodes using ansible-2.0

Tags: python, ansible

I downloaded the ansible-2.0.0-0.2.alpha2.tar.gz and installed it on my control machine. However now I'm not able to ping any of my machines. Previously using v1.9.2 i could communicate with them. Now it gives the following error:

```
    Unexpected Exception: lstat() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
the full traceback was:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/ansible", line 79, in 
sys.exit(cli.run())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/cli/adhoc.py", line 111, in run
inventory = Inventory(loader=loader, variable_manager=variable_manager, host_list=self.options.inventory)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/init.py", line 77, in init
self.parse_inventory(host_list)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/init.py", line 133, in parse_inventory
host.vars = combine_vars(host.vars, self.get_host_variables(host.name))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/init.py", line 499, in get_host_variables
self.vars_per_host[hostname] = self.get_host_variables(hostname, vault_password=vault_password)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init.py", line 529, in get_host_variables
vars = combine_vars(vars, self.get_host_vars(host))
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init_.py", line 653, in get_host_vars
return self.get_hostgroup_vars(host=host, group=None, new_pb_basedir=new_pb_basedir)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ansible/inventory/__init_.py", line 702, in _get_hostgroup_vars
base_path = os.path.realpath(os.path.join(basedir, "host_vars/%s" % host.name))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 365, in realpath
if islink(component):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 132, in islink
st = os.lstat(path)
TypeError: lstat() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the kind of thing you can expect when you are running an alpha release of any software. File a bug report on the Ansible github repo and then use a proper release.

Comment: @ydaetskcor Ok. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug due to some Unicode changes made to the playbook parser in 2.0. Several versions of Python shipped with a version of shlex.split() that fails horribly on Unicode input- you likely have one of them installed. The bug has been worked around and will be included in the next drop. See https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12257